# How to get related data with many-to-many relationship table?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, many-to-many

I have three tables. The first one is `Movie`, the second one `Category`, and the third one `MovieCategory`. I listed movies, but I want to choose a category and then list the movies for each category.

How do I make the controller? I've included my business objects, view, and current controller below.

Movie Entity

```cs
public class Movie : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Banner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MoviesCategory> MoviesCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Category Entity

```cs
public class Category : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MoviesCategory> MoviesCategory { get; set; }
}
```

MovieCategory Entity

```cs
public class MoviesCategory : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category  { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```cs
public IActionResult List()
{
    var movies = _movieService.GetAll();
    MovieListViewModel movieListViewModel = new MovieListViewModel()
    {
        Movies = movies
    };
    return View(movieListViewModel);
}
```

View

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Summary) && item.Summary.Length > 35)
            {
                <p>@(item.Summary.Substring(0,35))</p>
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Director)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="~/images/@item.Banner" width="105" height="140" class="img-thumbnail" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="~/Movie/Edit/@item.Id"><i title="Edit" class="fas fa-edit" style="color:coral"></i></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="~/Movie/Detail/@item.Id"><i title="Detail" class="fas fa-info-circle" style="color:cornflowerblue"></i></a>
        <td>
    <tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a `Category` and its related `Movies` do the following:

Create a view model that holds the data for `Category` and `Movies` in order to have a strongly typed view:

```cs
public class MovieData 
{
   public Category Category { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller you query the database like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> MovieDataAction(int catId)
{
    var data = await context
    .Categories
    .Where(c => c.Id == catId) //Category Id
    .Include(c => c.MoviesCategory)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Movie)
    .Select(cat => new { Category = cat, Movies = cat.MoviesCategory.Select(w => w.Movie) })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var vData = new MovieData(){
      Category = data.Category,
      Movies = data.Movies
    };

     return View(vData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo based on your description like below:

**View:**

```
@model MovieListViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "List";
}

<h1>List</h1>

@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.CategoryId, Model.Categories, "Select Category",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })

<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Summary) && item.Summary.Length > 35)
                {
                    <p>@(item.Summary.Substring(0,35))</p>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Director)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="~/Movie/Edit/@item.Id"><i title="Edit" class="fas fa-edit" style="color:coral"></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a href="~/Movie/Detail/@item.Id"><i title="Detail" class="fas fa-info-circle" style="color:cornflowerblue"></i></a>
            <td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $("#CategoryId").on("change", function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = "/Movie/List?id=" + id;
    })
</script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult List(int? id)
{
    var movies = _context.Movies.ToList();
        
    var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();

    if(id != null)
    {
        movies = _context.MoviesCategories.Where(c => c.CategoryId == id).Select(m => m.Movie).ToList();
    }

    MovieListViewModel movieListViewModel = new MovieListViewModel()
    {
        CategoryId = id ?? 0,
        Categories = new List<SelectListItem>(),
        Movies = movies
    };

    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        movieListViewModel.Categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = category.CategoryName, Value = category.Id.ToString() });
    }
    return View(movieListViewModel);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]